# Vim: Checking for blank lines below to keep the cursor position at the center

Tags: vim

When I start with a new program, the cursor eventually gets to the bottom of the screen. I want it to remain at the center, I managed this with following in vimrc file.

```
autocmd InsertEnter * :set scrolloff=9999
autocmd InsertLeave * :set scrolloff=0
```

But when I make small changes in the code, the cursor jumps to the middle of the screen which is a bit annoying. I would like to know, how to check conditions for next blank lines(say 5), before vim executes the above commands i.e `set scrolloff`. I could start with 5 blank lines at the bottom while writing new code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to map `scrolloff=9999` and hit that key when you know you are going to start on new code instead of some elaborate scheme to make it automatic?

Comment: That is a simpler option, but I think I would go with the solution given by @IngoKarkat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To determine how many lines the cursor is away from the bottom of the current window, you can use

```
:echo winheight(0) - winline()
```

So, to only make the cursor jump to the middle if its in the last 5 lines, you could use:

```
autocmd InsertEnter * if winheight(0) - winline() < 5 | set scrolloff=9999 | endif
```

I don't fully understand what kind of condition you have in mind with the blank lines, but you can check individual lines with `empty(getline(lnum))`. Also, the built-in functions `prevnonblank()` / `nextnonblank()` might be useful.